# Is there a way to stop Google Chrome from showing most visited sites on a blank tab?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I open a new tab in Google Chrome I see the Google search bar plus 8 thumbnails of recently visited (or most visited) sites. I never click on the thumbnails and find them to be annoying. Is there anyway to disable this in Chrome?

I can think of a hacky workaround like creating a blank page someplace and setting that to be the new tab page, but there must be a better way. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody answered I thought I would post and answer to my question:

Use the [Empty New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij) extension for a new **blank** tab instead of the default new tab.

There are also some redirect extensions such as [Momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=en), which loads a different full screen image each day.

Answer (score 1):

type `chrome://flags` then Disable **"Top Sites from Site Engagement"**

Comment: This does nothing

Comment: It seems that every single version of Chrome need its specific solution :D

Comment: wow, who knew there were so many options in chrome --- that seems like a secret page.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome allows extensions to run on chrome:// urls so one such possible future solution is if AdBlock explicitly requests the permission to run on chrome://newtab then you can just block the div with id most-visited. But currently AdBlock does not request this permission.

You could edit the manifest of AdBlock manually to include this permission or suggest it as a future feature.

Answer (score 0):

The default new tap page's url is `chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html`. You can press F12 to check it. It's a local resource located in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\{Version}\resources.pak`

or

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\{Version}\resources.pak`

Open it with a HEX editor, search text

`cur.style.opacity = 1.0`

, and replace it with

`cur.style.opacity = 0.0`

Tested on Chrome 77.0.3865.90 .